# hive server is not starting, getting stuck at that stage

Tags: hadoop, hive

When started hive it does not go further, it will stop at this stage as specified in the image. please any solutions?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: You need to go hive logs and see what is the problem

Comment: what does hive log say??